# mail sending error in php

Tags: email, phpmailer, php

I'm facing an error with PHP's `mail()` function. The `mail()` function can successfully send mail to gmail, ymail, rediffmail, etc. But in case of webmail, it fails.

I haven't found any reason for that.

Please help.

Comment: you need to show your not-working code...

Comment: what do your mail server logs say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the receipients adress correct?
Maybe you nee a qualified SMTP Server signature!

I added a line to your code

```
$mailbody="Hi"; 
$cheaders = "From: <admin@mysite.com>\n"; 
$cheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n"; 
$cheaders .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
$recipient="info@mysite2.com"; 
$subject="Test"; 

ini_set('sendmail_from', 'me@domain.com'); // Set your Sendingadress here

mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody , $cheaders);
```

Let me know if it works with that

Comment: are there any errors u get? could u please post ur code here?

Comment: $mailbody="Hi";
    $cheaders = "From: <admin@mysite.com>\n";
    $cheaders .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $cheaders .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";$recipient="info@mysite2.com";
    $subject="Test";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody , $cheaders);

Comment: just edited my answer. Try it in your application.